# Rails 3.2 ActiveAdmin 'Collection is not a paginated scope.' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm developing an application using Rails 3.2 and ActiveAdmin 0.4.4.
I have model named Teaser (/app/models/teaser.rb):

```
class Teaser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :img, :name, :url
  validates :img, :name, :presence => true
  mount_uploader :img, TeaserUploader
end
```

And I added ActiveAdmin to it  (/app/admin/teaser.rb):

```
# encoding: UTF-8
ActiveAdmin.register Teaser do
    form do |f|
        f.inputs "Teaser" do
            f.input :name, :label => 'Текст'
            f.input :url, :label => 'Ссылка'
            f.input :img, :as => :file, :label => 'Картинка'
        end
        f.buttons
    end
end
```

Now, when I go to 'http://localhost:3000/admin/teasers', I get the following error:

Showing C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:
Collection is not a paginated scope. Set collection.page(params[:page]).per(10) before calling :paginated_collection.

I get the same error when I test my app on linux (Ubuntu 12.04).

I can solve this problem by this way (/app/admin/teaser.rb):

```
# encoding: UTF-8
ActiveAdmin.register Teaser, :as => 'Somename' do
```

But if I use this method, I cannot translate this model by using /app/config/locales/XX.yml

All other models work properly.

Answer (score 10):

In some cases all you need to do is change the model's label in active admin

Example

**BREAKS**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Stage do
```

**WORKS**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Stage, as: "Opportunity Stage" do
```

The same case is for a model **Page**

***Update: 30-May***

I've run into this issue again, with a model like

> ActiveAdmin.register PageRedirects do

and in the **application_controller.rb** I had this:

```
before_filter :abc

def abc
  @page_redirects = ...
end
```

This method overrides the @page_redirects from the active-admin controller I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution (/app/models/teaser.rb)

```
collection_action :index, :method => :get do
  scope = Teaser.scoped
  @collection = scope.page() if params[:q].blank?
  @search = scope.metasearch(clean_search_params(params[:q]))
end
```

Comment: Same problem here. My admin page was working well and suddenly Boom! Your piece of code has solved the problem...

Comment: page needs an argument, do you use `params[:page]`?

Answer (score 4):

You may have a variable with the same name as the controller that is conflicting. Maybe in your application_controller.rb?

Comment: is clear and an excellent point, thanks, i do have variables with the same name in mi application controller, i rename those and everything works fine, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just improving the answer... I had problems when using the active admin filters, so I had to modify a little bit the code. Its working for me now.

```
collection_action :index, :method => :get do
  scope = Teaser.scoped
  @search = scope.metasearch(clean_search_params(params[:q]))
  @collection =  @search.page()  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me in rails 4.1

In the discussion at the [github issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1025#issuecomment-24894987) it turns out that this is caused by the fact that **active admin is inheriting from the application controller**.
So to answer this question, I suppose the bug is caused by assigning some collection to @teasers in the application controller.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please rename resource name on active admin page like

```
ActiveAdmin.register Teaser, as: "Some other name" do
```

This solved my issue.

I think this is due to conflict of resource name.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a default scope in active admin solved the issue for me.

```
ActiveAdmin.register StaticPage, as: 'Static Page' do
  scope :all, default: true
  # ...
end
```