# Ruby on Rails - Active Admin: Conflict with a Global Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

On Rails 4 with the latest version of Active Admin (using Ransack). I have an Award model that I made available globally in my application_controller.rb:

```
  before_action :set_awards

  private
    def set_awards
      @awards = Award.all
    end
```

This is so I could have a global navigation dropdown listing all awards (on the public side). I think this is conflicting with Active Admin. When I went to the Awards index page, I got the following error message:

```
Collection is not a paginated scope. Set collection.page(params[:page]).per(10) before calling :paginated_collection.
```

I am not sure what this means exactly but since this is the only model this happens to, I'm guessing it has something to do with my code in the app controller. I think my problem is similar to this question:

[Rails 3.2 ActiveAdmin 'Collection is not a paginated scope.' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033944/rails-3-2-activeadmin-collection-is-not-a-paginated-scope-error)

...I would prefer not to change the model's label and the metasearch code provided doesn't work because (I think) Active Admin now uses Ransack. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem and it was a variable name i was declaring at the application controller that was conflicting with the ActiveAdmin.

I have a model called Post and in my applicationController i had a method like this:

```
def load_posts
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

It returned me the error you mention, so i fixed it changing the variable name to:

```
def load_posts
  @post_list = Post.all
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be you overwrited a local variable @awards in ApplicationController, but Active Admins is inheriting from the application controller.
Just rename your variable and it will run.

Comment: Can I deny ActiveAdmin extend my ApplicationController?

Comment: I dont know. May be you just try) But I dont think is right try