# Ruby on Rails: ActiveAdmin scope using Array showing wrong records counting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I have been struggle with this for a couple of days know.

I have an ActiveAdmin page, that is pulling information from different Db's.

I created a couple of scope sections to handle different categories. The code of the ActiveAdmin looks something similar to this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyItem do

  scope :all

  scope :first_db do |myitem|
     myitem.where(deleted: false)
  end

  scope :FromDBs, show_count=>true do |myitem|
   Kaminari.paginate_array(MyItem.get_from_dbs).page(params[:page])
  end

  index do
  column :name
  column :value

end
```

Now, the issue I'm having, is with scope "FromDBs". It shows on the top as the record count
the amount of records as 25 (that is my page size for pagination) and not the total amount
of records in the array. If I go to the footer of the page, the "Next" button shows the correct amount of records.

So, my question would be, how I can do to make the "scope" section to show the
amount of records on the array and not the amount of record per page.

At some extend I tried to follow some of the recomendation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033944/rails-3-2-activeadmin-collection-is-not-a-paginated-scope-error), but not really
working for me. That is why I'm using Kaminari to be able to paginate the array.

Thanks for any pointer.

Comment: Why don't you define scopes in your model class? It'd be easier to define scopes in model and just use them in an ActiveAdmin resource definition.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily define your scopes in an ActiveAdmin resource block, Instead you want your scope definitions in your model class. I have a similar setup like below:

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active,    -> { where deleted_at: nil }
  scope :inactive,  -> { where.not deleted_at: nil }
  ...
end
```

```
ActiveAdmin.register Manager do
  scope :active, default: true
  scope :inactive
end
```

This handles records counts accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That would work great, if my model would be only retrieving data from one DB. On The scenario I tried to described, the model is pulling from different databases, so my model is returning an array with the results from different dbs. Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: What does get_from_dbs method look like? I don't understand what 'from different databases` mean. Did you mean separated database tables?